# Get substring of each element in a list and get them distinct in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I need to transform an XML file with XSLT, and this task is kinda tricky.

I have attributes with the name `attr_1000_a` whereas the number and the suffix are dynamic, so that `attr_2000_b` is valid too.

Further, there are `<row>` elements which combine related data. I need to transform them so that equally numbered attributes (i.e. `attr_1000_a` and `attr_1000_b`) are put into the same element.

Let me give you an example. Following input XML:

```
<root>
  <row id="1">
    <foo attr_1000_a="true">1</foo>
    <foo attr_1000_b="true">2</foo>
    <foo attr_1000_c="true">3</foo>
  </row>
  <row id="2">
    <foo attr_1000_a="true" attr_1000_b="true" attr_1000_c="true">10</foo>
    <foo attr_2000_a="true" attr_2000_b="true" attr_2000_c="true">20</foo>
  </row>
  <row id="3">
    <foo attr_1000_a="true" attr_2000_a="true" attr_3000_a="true">100</foo>
    <foo attr_1000_b="true" attr_2000_b="true" attr_3000_b="true">200</foo>
    <foo attr_1000_c="true" attr_2000_c="true" attr_3000_c="true">300</foo>
  </row>
</root>
```

You can see that the attributes can be combined in several ways, which makes the transformation difficult. Each attribute is unique in each `<row>` but can be located in any  `<foo>` element. Also, each `<foo>` can have an arbitrary number of attributes.

The desired result:

```
<result>
  <row id="1">
    <field attr="1000">
      <a>1</a>
      <b>2</b>
      <c>3</c>
    </field>
  </row>
  <row id="2">
    <field attr="1000">
      <a>10</a>
      <b>10</b>
      <c>10</c>
    </field>
    <field attr="2000">
      <a>20</a>
      <b>20</b>
      <c>20</c>
    </field>
  </row>
  <row id="3">
    <field attr="1000">
      <a>100</a>
      <b>200</b>
      <c>300</c>
    </field>
    <field attr="2000">
      <a>100</a>
      <b>200</b>
      <c>300</c>
    </field>
    <field attr="3000">
      <a>100</a>
      <b>200</b>
      <c>300</c>
    </field>
  </row>
</result>
```

I think i have to somehow get a list of all numbers in a row (for example 1000, 2000 and 3000) and then iterate through all elements that have such an attriute.

How can i do this using XSLT? Is this even possible?

Comment: Yes, this is possible and not difficult at all.

Comment: i'd appreciate a pointer to that easy solution

Comment: Alp: You already got two good solutions. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Quick and Dirty, this xslt**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <result>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </result>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="foo/@*">
        <xsl:element name="{substring-after(local-name(),'000_')}">
            <xsl:value-of select=".."/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="row">
        <row id="{@id}">
            <xsl:for-each-group select="foo/@*" group-by="substring(local-name(),1,9)">
                <field attr="{substring-after(current-grouping-key(),'attr_')}">
                   <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                </field>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </row>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="foo">
        <xsl:apply-templates  select="@*"/>
    </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**applied to this input**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <row id="1">
        <foo attr_1000_a="true">1</foo>
        <foo attr_1000_b="true">2</foo>
        <foo attr_1000_c="true">3</foo>
    </row>
    <row id="2">
        <foo attr_1000_a="true" attr_1000_b="true" attr_1000_c="true">10</foo>
        <foo attr_2000_a="true" attr_2000_b="true" attr_2000_c="true">20</foo>
    </row>
    <row id="3">
        <foo attr_1000_a="true" attr_2000_a="true" attr_3000_a="true">100</foo>
        <foo attr_1000_b="true" attr_2000_b="true" attr_3000_b="true">200</foo>
        <foo attr_1000_c="true" attr_2000_c="true" attr_3000_c="true">300</foo>
    </row>
</root>
```

**yields this result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
    <row id="1">
      <field attr="1000">
         <a>1</a>
         <b>2</b>
         <c>3</c>
      </field>
   </row>
    <row id="2">
      <field attr="1000">
         <a>10</a>
         <b>10</b>
         <c>10</c>
      </field>
      <field attr="2000">
         <a>20</a>
         <b>20</b>
         <c>20</c>
      </field>
   </row>
    <row id="3">
      <field attr="1000">
         <a>100</a>
         <b>200</b>
         <c>300</c>
      </field>
      <field attr="2000">
         <a>100</a>
         <b>200</b>
         <c>300</c>
      </field>
      <field attr="3000">
         <a>100</a>
         <b>200</b>
         <c>300</c>
      </field>
   </row>
</result>
```

**the magic is in**

```
    <xsl:element name="{substring-after(local-name(),'000_')}">
        <xsl:value-of select=".."/>
    </xsl:element>
```

this creates the a/b/c elements with a dynamic name and travels up one node to get the value from the parent node (we're currently in the attribute).

**and in**

```
        <xsl:for-each-group select="foo/@*" group-by="substring(local-name(),1,9)">
            <field attr="{substring-after(current-grouping-key(),'attr_')}">
               <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
            </field>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
```

which regroups all attributes (`foo/@*`) using part of *their* name (`substring(local-name(),1,9)`). The first are subsequently available as `current-group()`, the latter as `current-grouping-key()`, as you can see.

Comment: A good solution, but you can improve on the brevity by using literals instead of constant xsl:element, and also attribute template instead of xsl:attribute. Eg: <row id="{@id}">

Comment: `for-each-group`! didn't know about that one. thanks for your solution and the exxplanations

Answer (score 3):

Here is a sample stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="k1" 
  match="row/foo/@*" 
  use="concat(generate-id(../..), '|', substring-before(substring-after(local-name(), '_'), '_'))"/>

<xsl:template match="root">
  <result>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </result>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="row">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="foo/@*[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k1', concat(generate-id(../..), '|', substring-before(substring-after(local-name(), '_'), '_')))[1])]" mode="field"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="foo/@*" mode="field">
  <field attr="{substring-before(substring-after(local-name(), '_'), '_')}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('k1', concat(generate-id(../..), '|', substring-before(substring-after(local-name(), '_'), '_')))"/>
  </field>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="foo/@*">
  <xsl:element name="{substring-after(substring-after(local-name(), '_'), '_')}">
    <xsl:value-of select=".."/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. all that `key` and `generate-id` stuff seems like magic to me though

Comment: It is Muenchian grouping http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml necessary with XSLT 1.0. Let us know whether you can use an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9, AltovaXML or XmlPrime and I am sure an XSLT 2.0 solution will look less like magic.

Comment: I see that someone else already posted an XSLT 2.0 solution so use that if you can use an XSLT 2.0 processor.

Comment: Yes, i am using an XSLT 2.0 processor. Sorry for not pointing it out earlier.